# Thread blocking based on boolean value

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task-parallel-library, blocking

I have a service which processes data from a queue:

```
while (true)
{
    if(!HaltProcessing)
    { 
        var messages = receivedQueue.GetMessages(MessageGetLimit);

        if (messages.Count() > 0)
        {
            ProcessQueueMessages(messages);
        }
        else
        {
            Task.Delay(PollingInterval);
        }
    }
}
```

There is a `HaltProcessing` property which, when set to true, pauses the processing of queue items.  I do this through the `if statement` as seen above.

Is there a better way to block the thread when `HaltProcessing` is `true` and unblock when `false`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use "WaitHandles".

[AutoResetEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.autoresetevent%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [ManualRestEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to achieve it.

```
private ManualRestEvent signal = new ManualRestEvent(false);//or true based on your req
//Setting true is to allow processing and false is to halt the processing

while (true)
{
    signal.WaitOne();
    var messages = receivedQueue.GetMessages(MessageGetLimit);

    if (messages.Count() > 0)
    {
        ProcessQueueMessages(messages);
    }
    else
    {
        Task.Delay(PollingInterval);
    }
}

bool SetHaltProcessing(bool value)
{
    if(value)
       signal.Reset();
    else
       signal.Set();
}
```

Use case

```
SetHaltProcessing(true);//To halt the processing
SetHaltProcessing(false);//To start the processing
```

Comment: If you don't need cross-process synchronization, it's usually more efficient to use `ManualRestEventSlim`. Also, that `Task.Delay()` won't do anything, you copied that bug from the question.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you step back to see the bigger picture: You don't need (and want) the loop to run, if `HaltProcessing` is set.

So my approach would be to put the logic into the `HaltProcessing` setter:

- Set to true: Just set a flag
- Set to false: Start the loop thread

To implement this:

- The loop thread (running the loop method) should just exit, if it sees the flag
- If the loop thread should be started, clear the flag, then lock the thread handle, and on winning a potential lock race start the thread

Answer (score 1):

1. Your `Task.Delay()` won't do anything, it *returns* a `Task` that will complete after the given interval. If you don't do anything with that `Task`, it's almost as if you didn't call it.
2. If you want to process items from a collection when there are some and block when the collection is empty, you should use `BlockingCollection`.

   Waiting for a certain time when the collection is empty is bad for two reasons:

   1. When an item is added to the queue, you won't start processing it immediately.
   2. You're wasting CPU checking the `Count` over and over when the collection is empty.
3. If want to wait while `HaltProcessing` is `true`, you can use `ManualResetEventSlim` for this. Though it's more natural to do that negated:

   ```
   private ManualResetEventSlim processingAllowedEvent =
       new ManualResetEventSlim(true);

   public bool ProcessingAllowed
   {
       get
       {
           return processingAllowedEvent.IsSet;
       }
       set
       {
           if (value)
               processingAllowedEvent.Set();
           else
               processingAllowedEvent.Reset();
       }
   }

   public void WaitUntilProcessingAllowed()
   {
       processingAllowedEvent.Wait();
   }
   ```

With all this, your loop would look something like this:

```
while (true)
{
    WaitUntilProcessingAllowed();

    ProcessQueueMessage(blockingCollection.Take());
}
```

This assumes that you're okay with processing one item after `ProcessingAllowed` is set to `false`. If that's not true, you would need more complex synchronization (probably using `CancellationToken`).

Answer (score 0):

You do realize that all you do is run constantly in that loop, checking if the `HaltProcessing` is true, and when it's false, you process something ... That's busy waiting at it's best, and it's not pretty.

You should have some logic to say:

- if there are items -> process them
- else -> go to sleep
- when new items come in -> wake the processor.